# Prevent multiple console logging output while clustering

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, v8

I'm using the `cluster` module for `nodejs`.

Here is how I have it set up:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
}else{
     console.log("Turkey Test");
}
```

Now, I am forking 6 threads (6 cores) on my PC. So, when debugging my app and reading data from the console, this will appear:

[image]

Is there anyway to make `console.log` output only once regardless of how many clusters are running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the fact that you can communicate with the workers, and send a message that tells each worker if it should log or not. You'd send it so that only one worker (The first one for example) should log:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork().send({doLog: i == 0});
  }
}else{
  process.on('message', function(msg) {
    if(msg.doLog) {
      console.log('Turkey Test');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Never would of thought of this and never seen `{key: i ==0}` used as an inline (if statement) in this example? What is this trickery!

Comment: `i == 0` is just an expression... it evaluates to a boolean value (true / false), and that becomes the value of the property in the object...

Comment: Ha, it's cool @Amit. I've never seen an inline expression like that in literal notation (not ur fault, mine) that's all. Thank you ~